# Installing homebrew on a new mac account permission denied

Tags: ruby, macos, permissions, homebrew

So i had this mac and created a new account , on this new account so there are two account on the computer. First a created the new account and set it to standard user but later i changed it to enable administrator rights. 
I went to install Homebrew using command
    $ ruby -e "($curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go/install

First it started downloading then i got the some ucceeding error saying error creating symlink and some files and reason was permission denied. When i try reinstalling it again it says that homebrew is already installed but when i run brew, command not found . How can i succeessfully  install homebrew and fix this permission denied issue please ?

Comment: I did in [this](http://superuser.com/questions/751149/get-around-permission-errors) way and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I've installed this one since a long time ago. So I cant recall the details. But I think the problem came out for you are not in the super user mode. Please enter sudo in the command line first, then run the install program.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have just removed the installed homebrew using rm rf and reinstalled again with the command above now with sudo.. Well now im experiencing a different problem, it says ' -e:67 warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777 Don't run this as root! ' :(

Comment: try fix path `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local` there `$user` it is user name

Comment: @Monk_Code is right, this is documented here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Installation. Sometimes it happens that other programs change the permissions on /usr/local.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the `brew` command working, you can type:

```
brew doctor
```

for a diagnostic output of other location permissions that `brew` needs in order to operate properly, such as `/Library/Caches/Homebrew`